# Create classdata for PROC TABULATE

Tags: sas

The following code creates 15 rows of CLASSDATA I need for a PROC TABULATE command.

```
    proc sql; create table foo(eventtime num,node char(100)); quit;
    proc sql;  insert into foo (eventtime, node)                                                                                         
    values(1, '')
    values(2, 'L')
    values(2, 'W')
    values(3, 'LL')
    values(3, "LW/WL")
    values(3, 'WW')
    values(4, 'LLL')
    values(4, "LLW/LW*")
    values(4, "WL*/WWL")
    values(4, 'WWW')
    values(5, 'LLLL')
    values(5, "LLLW/LLW*/LWLL")
    values(5, "LWLW/LWW*/WLL*/WLWL")
    values(5, "WLWW/WWL*/WWWL")
    values(5, 'WWWW');                                                                                                                                                                                                         
quit;
```

How can I edit the code to create two new entries at each row level of 'YES' AND 'NO' and then four further entries at each of those rows for the following four options 50, 100, 150, 200? In total, that will be 120 rows.

Comment: Please attach a sample expected output as it would be clearer and your wording is not very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you need to add after your two PROC SQLs  something like this:

```
data foo120;
  set foo;
  do NewVar1='YES','NO';
    do NeVar2=50 to 200 by 50;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```